# Trying to save imageView image to gallery, but cannot saved to gallery.(Android)

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I'm trying to make a really simple app which allow users write on the image provided and save it to their gallery.
And I tried the code below, and it can't be saved.
Could you tell me which part I need to edit?

```
 ImageView imagecp = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar, menu);


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.savebutton:
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imagecp.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            Save savefile = new Save();
            savefile.SaveImage(this, bitmap);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"image saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


}
```

---

```
public class Save {
private Context TheThis;
private String NameOfFolder = "/Amir_Paint";
private String NameOfFile   = "APaintImage";

public void SaveImage(Context context,Bitmap ImageToSave){
    TheThis = context;
    String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ NameOfFolder;
    String CurrentDateAndTime= getCurrentDateAndTime();
    File dir = new File(file_path);

    if(!dir.exists()){
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(dir, NameOfFile +CurrentDateAndTime+ ".jpg");

    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ImageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        MakeSureFileWasCreatedThenMakeAvabile(file);
        AbleToSave();

    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {UnableToSave();}
    catch (IOException e){UnableToSave();}



}



private void MakeSureFileWasCreatedThenMakeAvabile(File file) {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(TheThis,
            new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            Log.e("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
            Log.e("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);

        }
    });

}



private String getCurrentDateAndTime() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    return formattedDate;
}


private void UnableToSave() {
Toast.makeText(TheThis, "Picture cannot saved to gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

private void AbleToSave() {
Toast.makeText(TheThis, "Picture saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

}

And error message below.

```
   09-30 14:30:30.311    3847-3863 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-30 14:30:30.311    3847-3863/ W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad761380, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-30 14:30:32.259    3847-3863/ E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab79e440
09-30 14:30:38.354    3847-3847/ W/art﹕ Long monitor contention event with owner method=void android.os.MessageQueue.nativeWake(long) from MessageQueue.java:4294967294 waiters=0 for 618ms
09-30 14:30:38.389    3847-4029/ W/art﹕ Long monitor contention event with owner method=void android.os.MessageQueue.nativeWake(long) from MessageQueue.java:4294967294 waiters=1 for 651ms
09-30 14:30:38.461    3847-3863/ E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab79e360
09-30 14:32:33.654    3847-3854/ W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 16.292ms
```

This is the permission I put on menifest file.

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: you should share your error messages as well.

Comment: `dir.mkdirs();`. Check the return value as it might fail. If false display a toast and return. You also could use .exists() again to see if the directory is created.

Comment: `"Picture cannot saved to gallery"`. That is not true. You could not save to a folder in external memory. Has nothing to do with the Gallery app or MediaStore. Moreover you should tell the user to which folder you tried to write a file. Use e.getMessage() when there is a catch.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the view instance inside of onCreateView method.

This is wrong.

```
ImageView imagecp = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

This is the right:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testclassfragment, container, false);
    imagecp = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    return v
}}
```

change this

```
String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ NameOfFolder;
```

with

```
String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + NameOfFolder;
```

Comment: I just put imagecp = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); this code inside onCreate method. But keep ImageView imagecp; this part outside so that I can reuse imagecp later on the code. And that works.

Comment: @JessJ thats why I called the instance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_variable

Comment: app doesn't crush, but cannot save the image.(IOException). Is there any other part I'm doing wrong? I added new error message.

Comment: @JessJ please be sure whether the bitmap is null or not. You can also share the code line that imagecp is set the bitmap

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imagecp.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            Save savefile = new Save();
            savefile.SaveImage(this, bitmap);

Comment: This is the code inside onOptionsItemSelected which is I already put on the question. hmm.. I set permisson(write & read) as well.

Comment: @JessJ how can you sure saving process is not working. Saved image name has a CurrentDateAndTime value. Please write a static value as a image name. And load the file and set the imageView

Comment: @JessJ I don't think this is about the permissions. If It was, you should get some exceptions.

Comment: UnableToSave() method was invoked and showed the message "Picture cannot saved to gallery"... That was why I was sure it has exception.  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {UnableToSave();}
    catch (IOException e){UnableToSave();} t

Comment: @JessJ you should also write the exception message using e. getMessage(); So you can be sure why you get the error

Comment: I varied the message, It was FileNotFoundException.

Comment: I still get filenotfound exception. Thanks for helping me..anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using [MediaStore insertImage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#insertImage(android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) instead of this old code.